# Inflating a view inside the viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

This is what I'm hoping to achieve:

[image]

**Step 1**: Click on the Green Button to open `View1.xml` on the ViewPager. (Works)

**Step 2**: Click on the Orange Button to open `SubView.xml` on the ViewPager. (Doesn't work)

So, I have set the onClick event for the orange button the following:

```
public void openForm(View view) {
    ViewGroup item = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.vp_horizontal_ntb); //this is the view pager
    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_post_form, null);
    item.addView(child);
}
```

**Results**:

Nothing. Nothing happens.

---

If I switch viewpager for linearlayout it opens (and breaks tab navigation). What I wanna do is open it on the viewpager, so it looks and behaves as if it's on a tab, until it's removed by clicking on another tab.

I also thought about putting a linear layout there and make `viewPager` gone while the `linearLayout` is set to visible. But I feel like there's a better solution than this.

Comment: What adapter is the ViewPager populated with?

Comment: I'm actually using [Devlight NavigationTab](https://github.com/Devlight/NavigationTabBar/), and [here's the whole code with the adapter](https://gist.github.com/madd86/e4a8e9667b2a552039905c81dff2a5de).